# Laravel, why do I use rollback

Tags: laravel, migration, rollback

I would like to know when do I need to use the rollback?

I understood the rollback is something to revert the DB structure, but (I think) it affects my local DB only.
If something is wrong in the structure, then is better to create another migration and pull to all team.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say when do you need to rollback. It depends on individual needs and circumstances. Laravel provides a way to rollback if someone needs to do it.

Sometimes changes in your database may break your existing functionality and you may need to rollback to get the previous state of your application or maybe you just want to exclude some functionality from your application and that's why you may need to rollback the changes you have made to your database but it's not a reason that this option is available, instead it's an option and you are not forced to do it.

Cricket players needs to lift some weight, it's a part of their exercise, even Footballers do it but they don't really need to lift any weight when they play on the field then why should they lift weight?

All options are not for everybody but the framework provides the functionalities to make it complete, that' it. if you ever need to use one option then you may use it otherwise leave it.